# serverless remove lamda using gitlab CI

Tags: aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, serverless-framework

I'm using gitlab CI for deployment.

I'm running into a problem when the review branch is deleted.

```
stop_review:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - echo "$AWS_REGION"
    - echo "Stopping review branch"
    - serverless config credentials --provider aws --key ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} --secret ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    - serverless remove --stage=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --verbose
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  when: manual
```

error is `This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory. Make sure to reference a valid config file in the current working directory if you're using a custom config file`

I have tried different `GIT_STRATEGY`, can some point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run `serverless remove`, you'll need to have the `serverless.yml` file available, which means the actual repository will need to be cloned. (or that file needs to get to GitLab in some way).

It's required to have a `serverless.yml` configuration file available when you run `serverless remove` because the Serverless Framework allows users to provision infrastructure using not only the framework's YML configuration but also additional resources (like CloudFormation in AWS) which may or may not live outside of the specified `app` or `stage` CF Stack entirely.

In fact, you can also provision infrastructure into other providers as well (AWS, GCP, Azure, OpenWhisk, or actually any combination of these).

So it's not sufficient to simply identify the stage name when running `sls remove`, you'll need the full `serverless.yml` template.

Comment: it did not work, I solved it by using artifacts [aka adding serverless.yml as artifcact]

Comment: That works too! As per my comment, `sls remove` will work as long as the `serverless.yml` file is available.

Can you mark this question as resolved?

Comment: out of curiosity  ,why its a hard requirement to have serverless.yml?

Comment: @ManishParab I updated my answer with more clarity. Hope it helps!